# Spark DataFrame to Google Cloud PubSub

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

I want to stream/ batch load data from a Spark DataFrame to the PubSub. I came across with some libraries like:

1. Apache Bahir: Useful for Streaming data from PubSub only.
   https://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/2.2.1/spark-streaming-pubsub/
2. PubSub Lite Connector: Capable to writing to PubSub Lite, not sure if this works for PubSub.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the [Pub/Sub Lite connector](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/write-messages-apache-spark) for writing messages to `Pub/Sub`. Though [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) & [Pub/Sub Lite](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/publish-receive-messages-console) both are horizontally `scalable and managed messaging services` but due to some differences these are two individual products.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/choosing-pubsub-or-lite) to check the differences between Pub/Sub and Pub/Sub Lite. From the doc:

> `Pub/Sub` is usually the default solution for most application integration and analytics use cases.
>
> `Pub/Sub Lite` is only recommended for applications where achieving `extremely low cost` justifies some additional operational work.

For stream/ batch load data from a `Spark DataFrame` to the `Pub/Sub` you can use [Apache Bahir](http://bahir.apache.org/)’s Pub/Sub connector. 
You can find this [example from Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-gcp-examples/tree/master/pubsub-streaming) where Apache Bahir’s [Spark Streaming connector for Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://github.com/apache/bahir/tree/master/streaming-pubsub) has been used.

Comment: Apache Bahir is used to stream data from Pub/Sub. I did not find any documentation around using Bahir to stream data to Pub/Sub. Can you please provide more information, if I am missing something here?